# Can someone tell me what technology this code is using?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been working MVC and stumbled on this code:

```
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: AddItems">
                <tr>
                    <td><select id="AllItemList" data-bind="options: $root.AllItems, optionsText: 'ItemName', optionsValue: 'ID', value: ID, optionsCaption: 'Select Item...'"></select></td>
```

I'd like to read up more on this but I'm not sure what I should be looking up?  This is much different than what I've been doing in the past using javascript to directly create the dynamic pieces. Creating the table in html and then using a foreach seems to be a lot cleaner than what I was doing previously.

What is this called?

Comment: its knockout .. I think.

Comment: Looks like knockout.js from `data-bind`

Comment: Too broad? Seems pretty specific to me!

Answer (score 4):

It is using knockout.js. For more information on knockout please visit the link [here](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Thank you!  Time for some coffee and going into learning mode.